# Import files from password-protected remote server

Tags: import

I would like to `Import` files which are stored at a password-protected remote server. Because the server is protected by a password `SetDirectory["/server/folder"]` fails. Are there any ideas how to fetch the files?

Comment: Did you try to use `Import` directly? It's supposed to present an interactive authentication dialog if necessary

Comment: Yes, I did try to use Import directly. I didn't get the interactive dialog. Just showed the error message: File not found during import

Comment: Then your server is probably using some authentication scheme that MMA does not support - can you provide more details regarding the server? What type of server is it? How do you normally access it? ...

Comment: The Server is a Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3, I occasionally copy files from the server using smbclient.

Comment: @RMMA did the suggestion in my answer work for this?

Comment: @GenericAccountName thanks for your effort. No it doesn't work. What I do now is mounting the Server. Then I can get the files.

Comment: @RMMA thanks for letting me know, good to keep these scenarios in mind. I updated the answer to have some general advice since a similar question may land folks on this page.

Answer (score 5):

Try `Import["/server/folder", "Username" -> "username", "Password" -> "password"]`

EDIT: For the record, this works if you can access the file from a browser, and it prompts you for a User/Pass.. This is an intended but undocumented feature of Import.