# Direct Import Remote File via SSH without Copying in Windows

Tags: import, remote-access, file-transfer

Is there any option to directly import to a Windows-driven Mathematica kernel a file from a remote server without copying it on hard drive? Right now I'm using  `CopyFile` with `RemoteFile` and `$SSHAuthentication`. It is very inconvenient because for every remote file I have to provide a path on harddrive to copy it and then use just regular `Import`. It there a workaround?

`Import["/server/folder", "Username" -> "username", "Password" -> "password"]` from [Import files from password-protected remote server](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174833/import-files-from-password-protected-remote-server) doesn't work, as well as `Import[RemoteFile[...]]`

Comment: Does the plan you accepted apply to you?

Comment: Yes, the edited answear works - You can use SSHFS-Manager (or sshfs command) to mount a remote drive and then just regular import within mathematica works, but it is considerably slower than just copy file to local hard drive via WinSCP and importing it from local drive to Mathematica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your know ssh, why not directly use linux commands like

```
 Import["!echo `ssh user@host 'cat  /home/user/file.txt'`", "String"]
```

You can avoid password request by simply sharing public/private key with your computer and server (see ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host  in ubuntu)

**Edit 1**
Other solution (not related to Mathematica) is to use sshfs command to mount remote server folder to local computer file system. Seems there are attempts to implement the functionality for windows as well. See, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67182778/mounting-linux-fs-in-windows-10-using-sshfs for instructions. After mounting remote folder effectively becomes a local folder, so every program can access files as if they were located on local computer.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer!I'm not familiar with linux commands since unfortunately I work on windows. I'm actually using ssh key pair but this approach doesn't work - it just imports the string in quotes. maybe I have to provide somehow a path to a private key before importing?

Comment: First, check if you can connect to the remote server without password. You can read this https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-use-putty-ssh  . In the end they have a section how to generate public key for putty. I think in windows the example will not work anyway, because the string "!echo ...." is in fact is linux terminal command. I suspect it is possible to write something similar in powershell, but I don't know it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'm using putty with ssh key and I can connect without password -  it works great (via WinSCP works as well). I don't really know how to connet from powershell, but when I find it i will try to use it in Mathematica. Thanks!

Comment: @Lechuu   Another solution which comes to mind is to use sshfs command to mount remote server folder to local computer file system. I use this routinely and I just checked that recently there were attempts to do this for windows also Look for example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67182778/mounting-linux-fs-in-windows-10-using-sshfs  . After mounting remote folder it effectively becomes as a local folder, so every program can access files as if they were located on local computer. Sometimes this is really convenient.

Comment: Thank You very much! It is exactly what I was looking for! If you could just edit Your answer so everyone could know the solution I would be very greateful.

Comment: It's seem [don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yigct.png) for me. Did I not understand your answer correctly?

Comment: @yode  That is for linux OS, not windows. May also work on mac.

Comment: `RemoteRunProcess` maybe more mmastyle

Answer (score 2):

I'm in Windows 11. If you are currently on a LAN, then I recommend using this scheme:

```
ImportString[URLRead["sftp://12.12.12.57/home/user/42.jpg", 
  Authentication -> <|"Username" -> "user", "Password" -> "yourpass"|>]]
```

Or directly:

```
ImportString[URLFetch["sftp://12.12.12.57/home/user/42.jpg","Username" -> "user", "Password" -> "yourpass"]]
URLExecute["sftp://12.12.12.57/home/user/42.jpg",Authentication -> <|"Username" -> "user", "Password" -> "yourpass"|>]
```

Or use the newest method in Acus:

```
Import["!ssh -i \"C:/Users/myname/.ssh/key\" yode@12.12.12.57 cat /home/user/42.jpg","JPEG"]
```

Or we can use `RemoteEvaluate`+`$DefaultRemoteKernel`:

```
RemoteEvaluate[KernelConfiguration["ssh://yode@12.12.12.57/usr/local/bin/wolfram", 
  "SshIdentity" -> "C:/Users/myname/.ssh/key"], Import["42.jpg"]]
```

Or use `RemoteRunProcess`+`RemoteConnect`:

```
ImportString[
 RemoteRunProcess["12.12.12.57" , "cat 42.jpg", "StandardOutput", 
  Authentication -> <|"Username" -> "user", "Password" -> "yourpass"|>]]
```

Or use `wolframscript`:

```
ImportString[RemoteRunProcess["12.12.12.57", 
"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.3/Executables/wolframscript \
-code 'Import[\"/home/user/42.jpg\"]' -format JPEG", "StandardOutput",
   Authentication -> <|"Username" -> "user", "Password" -> "yourpass"|>]]
```

However, `wolframscript` starts an mma kernel each time it runs, which is slow unless you use `wolframscript -wstpserver`. But use `wolframscript -wstpserver`, need to advance in the server startup `SystemFiles/Links/wstpserver/wstpserver`

Comment: Very interesting, so many solutions. However some uses plain password input, which is consider as very unsafe. On linux we never display it, therefore I would prefer solutions with SshIdentity.

Comment: @Acus The input method of the password is not important, basically all methods can use the password and key two ways